# How can I open a specific commit from the Sha in visual studio

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013

I like using the Visual Studio interface for a lot of my work.  I have a specific sha hash and I would like to view the commit details in VS.  Is this possible?

Comment: Played with my VS a bit (VS 2013 update 4) and could not find it in the UI. However, iv Visual Studio Online works for you then you can simply compose the url with the commit hash you'd like to view. Would this work for you?

Comment: `git show <sha>`, learn to use the terminal. Git is not designed for interfaces to work well with

Answer (score 2):

I've been looking for the same thing, and came up with a git alias inspired by @Amnon Schochot's reply.

```
[alias]
vc = "!f() { git web--browse http://MyCompanysGitServer/MyRepository/commit/"$1"; }; f"
```

Now you can load the commit in the browser by typing:

```
git vc 52cde98067ba9b258ec965a65852777459e4b3ba
```

Hope this helps a bit.

I think MS is just slack for not yet having provided a way to open details for a specific commit inside visual studio itself, when clearly the functionality is there (you can right click a commit in the history and choose "View Commit Details").